# Resizing images on iPhone for UITableView image

Tags: iphone, image, tableview

I'm using a sectioned TableView, and I want to show an image on the left side of the cell. 
If I pick one from the photo library (out of the example photos in simulator) and set it as UITableViewCell.imageView.image, it takes up the whole screen.

How can I resize the image so that it fits exactly into the cell's image view?

Thanks,

Yassin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically the same question as [How to scale a UIImageView proportionally ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185652/how-to-scale-a-uiimageview-proportionally), which has a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185652/how-to-scale-a-uiimageview-proportionally/537697#537697).

Add that category to your project and call it with the size of your view. I've used the code and it works well.