# Resize View in iPad

Tags: ipad

I am trying to convert my iphone app to ipad app. My problem is when i run this i am not able to resize the screen.In my iphone app i use one imageView, When itried to run on ipad it was showing same imaegeview three times side by side, I have to adjust this as one imageview.Can any body pls help me out for this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about your problem?

Comment: sure, actually i one imageview in in m iphone app. when i try to run this on iPad it was showing 3 imageviews in one screen. I think i have to adjust size of the screen in iPad, for showing single image.

Comment: i dont know how to resize the view.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be doing strange image resizing, your best option would be to look at look at this thread:

[How to scale a UIImageView proportionally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185652/how-to-scale-a-uiimageview-proportionally)

However, you should be regenerating your images for the different screen resolutions (otherwise they will look like an SNES game).