# How to programmatically choose a default thumbnail image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a tableView based app and I made a custom TableViewCell that have a thumbnail in it.
I wish to programmatically choose a default thumbnail image for my custom TableViewCell.
any ideas on how to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set **tag** for your `UIImageView` in your custom `UITableViewCell`, for example, let it be **10**.

When you want to show image in that view for some `UITableViewCell *cell;` do next:

```
UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewForTag:10];
imageView.image = [UIImage ....];
```

Comment: Thanks but how do i resize that image?

Comment: found it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185652/how-to-scale-a-uiimageview-proportionally/537697#537697)

Comment: You should just set `imageView.frame` with needful size. And set appropriate `imageView.contentMode`

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (void)setCellIconImage:(UIImage*)iconImage
    {
        self.imgView.image = iconImage;
    }
```