# How to add large background image on the UIView in a full size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have a high resolution image and I want to use it as a background for a view. But when I add it either via an Interface Builder or programatically I see only its part.This doesn't help:

```
UIImage* _backGround = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background-clean@2x.png"];
  CGRect _viewFrame = self.view.frame;
 [_backGround drawInRect:_viewFrame];
UIImageView* _backGroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:_backGround];
[self.view addSubview:_backGroundView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:_backGroundView];
```

And this too:

```
_backGroundView.contentMode =UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

So the question how can I scale this image in order it fits in the view in a full size in spite of its size?
P.S. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185652/how-to-scale-a-uiimageview-proportionally

Comment: what is the name of the image?

Comment: @holex Does this matter?"background.png"

Comment: @Gereon This doesn't help.I see only part of the image

Comment: @HarryCater, **EDITED:** of course it is matter! if the image resolution is for retina screen you have to rename the image to `background@2x.png` for showing the image on the retina or normal screen correctly.

Comment: @HarryCater, you can read more here the **[App-Related Resources](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html)** of the official developers' documentations.

Comment: Please explain what "its part" means: how large (in pixels) is background-clean.png, and what is the size of the view? Maybe what you're looking for is image resizing like it's shown here: http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Ali, when creating retina-sized images you should also scale them and add their smaller version to your project. With both versions you can simply specify the full name of the image **without** the `@2x.png` or `.png` extension.

But, to fix your implementation you only need one extra line of code:

```
UIImage* _backGround = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background-clean"];
UIImageView* _backGroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:_backGround];

_backGroundView.frame = self.view.frame;

[self.view addSubview:_backGroundView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:_backGroundView];
```

Once you change the `frame` of the `UIImageView`, its contents (i.e. your image) will scale as well.

Comment: Thanks. Great and simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

You must not include `@2x` in your code when referencing the name of the image!

You should:

- Include both files `Background.png` and `Background@2x.png` in your Xcode projet resources, `Background@2x.png` being twice the size (in pixels) of `Background.png`
- But always refer to this file (for example in `imageNamed:`) as `@"Background.png"` or even just `@"Background"`: `[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background"]`

Then iOS will do its magic all by itself, choosing the right image between `Background.png` or `Background@2x.png` depending on if the device screen is Retina or not.

For more info [see here in Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreensInViews/SupportingHiResScreensInViews.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background-clean"]]];
```