# UIImageView Aspect Ratio?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, aspect-ratio, contentmode

I have an image of size **320X460** and I want to create an `UIImageView` which height should be **450**. To maintain aspect ratio I calculated the width of UIImageView = (320/460)*450 = 313.043 dynamically. And set the contentMode For UIImageView is **UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit**. And set the image(320x460) to image view but it is some what blur.

Note: If I don't resize the `UIImageView` to **313.043X450** the image is very clear as it is. So what is the mistake I have done?

Comment: don't set the content-mode for the UIImageView if you are resizing it

Comment: also, try to make the sizes ints. Simply use round: round(313.043)

Comment: @RatikantaPatra. I am not resizing the uiimage I am resizing the UIImageView so If I don't set content mode It will shrink...

Comment: @EsbenB That is not solution i think...

Comment: RatikantaPatra suggests that you set the contentMode to UIViewContentModeScaleToFill. When you resize an image there is always of risk of blurring the image. In this case the UIimageView needs to "compress" a few pixels

Comment: @EsbenB Please refer jackson's answer with picture representation in the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185652/how-to-scale-a-uiimageview-proportionally

Comment: lol. anyways... provide related screenshots (before and after resizing the `UImageView`) and include it in your question so we get a better idea of what is happening and what you expect.

Comment: @IOSDeveloper don't set he contentMode property at all. It takes the default value UIViewContentModeScaleToFill. Simple set the image i.e 
imageView.image=yourImage. That should do

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, this should answer it.

First to set the aspect ratio for the image in your image view.

`myView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit`

Next, your image may blur because it is a `.png` or another rasterized format.  You need to use `.pdf` [as recommended by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017-245/?time=1294) or at very least another vectorized format.  Rasterized images have values for all pixels in the image, so when the image is stretched too far it just duplicates and blurs pixels.  Vectorized images do not blur because they are really just a series of instructions on how to draw/render the corresponding image. [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are resizing `UIImageView` manually, set the content mode to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`.

If you want to keep content mode `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` do not resize imageview to 313. Image will adjust maximum possible width and height , keeping it's aspect ratio.