# Proportionally resize UIImage by width

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage

I need to resize `UIImage` proportionally by width, may be someone have a working code?

For ex.:

> Input:  Width: 900 Height: 675. Resize to width: 400 width
>
> Result: Width: 400 Height: 300

Please help..

Comment: What have you tried?  Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/537697/1066424

Comment: I dont have "targetSize", I have only width, not height

Comment: newHeight = newWidth / oldWidth * oldHeight

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check [this blog post](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/) out. In particular, these two files:

- [UIImage+Resize.h](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/UIImage+Resize.h)
- [UIImage+Resize.m](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/UIImage+Resize.m)

Maybe this would work for you:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SomeImage-900x675"]; // SomeImage-900x675.png
CGFloat targetWidth = 400.0f;

CGFloat scaleFactor = targetWidth / image.size.width;
CGFloat targetHeight = image.size.height * scaleFactor;
CGSize targetSize = CGSizeMake(targetWidth, targetHeight);

UIImage *scaledImage = [image resizedImage:targetSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];
```

Comment: I need height like in Photoshop, when you set new size of image and inputing new weight, it says new height programmatically..

Comment: so I need a formula.. may be you have it?

Comment: I edited my answer to include an example usage. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: Wouldn't targetHeight be a factor of size.height, not size.width?

Comment: @TahoeWolverine Good catch. I've corrected the sample.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just set the content mode? to .ScaleAspectFill? Then you can set the UIImageView size to any arbitrary size and the aspect ratio will be preserved.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontentmode/1622518-scaleaspectfill

Comment: Sweet, thanks!  I never thought of checking that... worked perfectly.