# user custom crop in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller, crop

I get image for imageView using `UIImagePickerController` like this

```
 -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *originalImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    CGSize destinationSize1 = CGSizeMake(200, 200);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(destinationSize1);
    [originalImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,destinationSize1.width,destinationSize1.height)];
    UIImage *newImage1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    firstimage1.image = newImage1;
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    NSLog(@"image width is %f",firstimage1.image.size.width);
    NSLog(@"image height is %f",firstimage1.image.size.height);
   if (firstimage1.image.size.width==200 && firstimage1.image.size.height==200) {
    UIAlertView *alertcrp=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"message!" message:@"you want to crop this image" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [alertcrp addButtonWithTitle:@"Crop "];
        [alertcrp show];
        }
}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSLog(@"Button Index =%ld",(long)buttonIndex);
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"You have clicked Cancel");
    }
    else if(buttonIndex == 1)
    {
   UIImagePickerController *controller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        controller.allowsEditing = YES; // this will allow you to crop the image first
        controller.delegate = self;

        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
}
```

We resize image to 200*200.Now What i need is When User is upload image .If image is upload success and then open alertView "if you want to Crop the image". Once click the crop button i need to Open Rectangle  crop View .

Please give me any idea about my problem.Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: do you need to crop (i.e. take only part of the image) or resize (use the whole image but scale if to fit 200x200)?

Comment: u need resize the image or crop the full image into half image

Comment: @marvin i need both like 
 i have upload button and crop button if customer no need to crop image will be resize and if customer need to crop ,customer click crop button and then Reszie

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i need both

Comment: You need to use GKClass on github https://github.com/gekitz/GKImagePicker.I hope this helps....

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty simple what you need to do. First create a `UIScrollView` of the crop size you want to crop, u can make it dynamic if you want to by pan gestures etc. But I have done with a constant crop size so I wont go into that detail. Next create an `UIImageView` of the size of your original image and set its `image proprety` to that. Also set your `scorllview's content size` property to the exact same as the image's size. Allow the bounces to have some extra effects. Then on press of crop you just need to pass the scrollview's contentoffset and size you want to be croped(that would be size of scrollview i.e. its width and height) to this function.

```
- (UIImage *)crop:(UIImage *)image inRect:(CGRect)cropRect
{
    CGImageRef cropRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, cropRect);
    UIImage* cropImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cropRef];
    CGImageRelease(cropRef);

    return cropImage;
}
```

You can call this method as per above description as

```
UIImage * img = [[CommonFunctions sharedManager] crop:imgView.image inRect:CGRectMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x , scrollView.contentOffset.y , reqWidth, reqHeight)];
```

There might be a bug with making the rect for cropping according to your logic. But you should have  general idea on what do. Do let me know if something confuses you or if it helps or not, so I might be able to help out further :)

Answer (score 0):

For resize an image use this

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(200, 200));
[myImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)]; // Size of your ne image
UIImage *resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImagePickerController *controller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

controller.allowsEditing = YES; // this will allow you to crop the image first
controller.delegate = self;

[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Then you will need to resize it to fit 200x200, you could try this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/537697/660907