# UIImage scaling down to smaller size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

So I have an image that is a circle which I want to scale down to a new size.

[image]

When I scale down, the resultant is a square with the circle with diameter = side of the square, and there is a white background color. How do I get an image that is exactly the same shape?

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image customScaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
//UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

[[UIColor clearColor] set];
UIRectFill(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height));

[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Maybe try this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/537697/2518285

Comment: That does not help. It would still be a square.

Comment: Your actual problem is the white color instead of clear background?

Comment: @phi Yes, circle image scaled down to smaller size has white background

Comment: So you're saying that your original image is a circle on a transparent background, but that when you scale it, you get a white background? Your code is similar to this very popular answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2658801/2518285 but yours has a UIRectFill, whereas the answer does not. Suggest trying without UIRectFill. And are you 100% sure your original image has a transparent background?

Comment: Yes, I am positive. Ive added the image to the question

Comment: I've tried the code in your question, with the image attached above, and the transparent parts of the image are maintained, with or without the `UIRectFill`. Can you add screenshots of the effect you're seeing? I suspect there's something else going on that is not included in the question.

Comment: Ok found the issue for it. I was saving the image to disk as JPEG with compression. FML. Did not see that. Saving as png is the right way to go.. Haha sorry for wasting all of your time

Comment: @jrturton really appreciate you trying out the code for me.

Comment: You should add that as an answer - JPEG doesn't support transparency.

Comment: Suggest you delete this question, seeing as it mentions scaling but the answer has nothing to do with scaling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the problem was that the image was saved as a JPEG right before scaling, and JPEG does not support transparency.

Saving as PNG was the right way to go.